# React How to get and watch for body text direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I'm building a component that needs to support both [text direction](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) (**ltr** and **rtl**)

In the main page, we use simple HTML and CSS to determine the text direction

```
<div data-testid="mountNode" id="slider-preview" class="virtual-body" dir="rtl">
   ...element
</div>
```

However, in my React component, I want to watch for this dir, so that I will do some manipulation inside

```
const Slider: FC<SliderProps> = props => {
  let isRTL = false;  // I want this to actually reflect the current direction of the page
  return (<div>{isRTL} ? 'RTL' : 'LTR' </div>)
}
```

**So my question is**

1/ How to get the current body direction in javascript

2/ I have a button to change the direction, basically, it will change the **dir** attribute of the `div wrapper`, how to make sure when it changes, the `Slider` component also update.

Thanks

Comment: Is `#slider-preview` rendered by react?

Comment: Not really, the wrapper is just a html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `dir` dynamically depends on your state management approach (props propagation, context, mobx, redux etc.).

Here is an example of a simple props propagation approach.

```
function Slider({ dir }) {
  return (
    <div dir={dir}>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [dir, setDir] = useState("ltr");
  return (
    <Slider dir={dir} />
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-sammet-u553m?file=/src/App.js

---

In order to **observe** changes in the parent `dir` (in case it's an external component), you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in props and update the state in accordingly.

```
const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(document.body.dir);
React.useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    if (mutationsList.some((mutation) => mutation.attributeName === "dir")) {
      setDirection(document.body.dir);
    }
  });
  observer.observe(document.body, {
    attributes: true
  });
  return () => observer.disconnect();
}, []);
```

A working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sanne-uomlk?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: yes this is how can i pass the dir to Slider, but what i mean is how can i detect it in the 1st place

Comment: Generally, you can use [`window.getComputedStyle(element).dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to check the slider's root element's `direction` (Like this: https://jsbin.com/tefidar/edit?html,css,js,console). You'll need to use `ref` in order to access the DOM element. But, I'd avoid using code and try hard (in most of the cases it is possible) to achieve the same result with css. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: I see what you mean. Because you know for a Slider, the css attached needs the JS logic ( because the filled bar of the slider depends on its current value, its not just changing direction like text). I also want to do 100% CSS but didn't find any clue.

Comment: ` window.getComputedStyle(element).dir` is not reactive, so like what I ask in question 2, if I have a button just to change directly the dir of the dom, it will not update my react component. I feel its quite impossible to do what i need in question 2, right ?

Comment: You can show me your code (maybe with codesandbox), css is very powerful and flexible, so it might be possible after all. About the 2nd section, maybe you can use `MutationObserver` to observe changes in the body (or the wrapper element) and set a local state accordingly. Something like: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sanne-uomlk?file=/src/App.tsx:210-226

Comment: hi thanks, I realize the reason why my components not change belongs to a different problem. For this context of this question only, I think. MutationObserver and your lastest sandbox example did the trick for my 2nd question. Will mark this as answer, you can append you answer if needed. Thanks